# FATAL ERROR CONTROLLER

Tags: extensions, magento2.2.3

I have install extension and I get the following error on frontend.

Fatal error: Declaration of `Apptha\Airhotels\Controller\Index\Index::execute()` must be compatible with `Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index::execute($coreRoute = NULL)` in

> public_html/app/code/Apptha/Airhotels/Controller/Index/Index.php

on line 52.

```
<?php
/**
 * Apptha
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the EULA
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://www.apptha.com/LICENSE.txt
 *
 * ==============================================================
 *                 MAGENTO EDITION USAGE NOTICE
 * ==============================================================
 * This package designed for Magento COMMUNITY edition
 * Apptha does not guarantee correct work of this extension
 * on any other Magento edition except Magento COMMUNITY edition.
 * Apptha does not provide extension support in case of
 * incorrect edition usage.
 * ==============================================================
 *
 * @category    Apptha
 * @package     Apptha_Airhotels
 * @version     1.0.0
 * @author      Apptha Team <developers@contus.in>
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2017 Apptha. (http://www.apptha.com)
 * @license     http://www.apptha.com/LICENSE.txt
 *
 */
namespace Apptha\Airhotels\Controller\Index;


class Index extends \Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index
{
    public function execute(){

         $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance ();
         //$airhotelsKey = $objectManager->get ( 'Apptha\Airhotels\Helper\Product' )->AirhotelsKey();
         $moduleEnableornot = $objectManager->get ( 'Apptha\Airhotels\Helper\Data' )->getEnableFrontend();

         if ($moduleEnableornot == 0) {
               /**
               * Notification Message
               */
           $msg = base64_decode('PGgzIHN0eWxlPSJmbG9hdDpsZWZ0O2NvbG9yOnJlZDttYXJnaW46IDMwMHB4IDQ3NXB4OyB3aWR0aDoyNiU7IiBpZD0idGl0bGUtdGV4dCI+RW5hYmxlIEFpcmhvdGVscyB0byB2aWV3IHRoZSB3ZWJzaXRlPC9oMz4=');

           $this->getResponse()->setBody ( $msg );
        } else {
              return  parent::execute();
         }
    }
}
```

Need Help please.

Comment: why you have declined the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your function name from `public function execute()` to `public function execute($coreRoute = null)`

Or replace your extended class to `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` if you don't want to inherit `\Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index` Class

Hope this will help you

Comment: Hello, Thank you but I get this following error again.

Comment: show me your error message

Comment: Fatal error: Multiple access type modifiers are not allowed in /home/app/code/Apptha/Airhotels/Controller/Index/Index.php on line 35

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ps9bfa

Comment: can you update your question with updated code

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/**
 * Apptha
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the EULA
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://www.apptha.com/LICENSE.txt
 *
 * ==============================================================
 *                 MAGENTO EDITION USAGE NOTICE
 * ==============================================================
 * This package designed for Magento COMMUNITY edition
 * Apptha does not guarantee correct work of this extension
 * on any other Magento edition except Magento COMMUNITY edition.
 * Apptha does not provide extension support in case of
 * incorrect edition usage.
 * ==============================================================
 *
 * @category    Apptha
 * @package     Apptha_Airhotels
 * @version     1.0.0
 * @author      Apptha Team <developers@contus.in>
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2017 Apptha. (http://www.apptha.com)
 * @license     http://www.apptha.com/LICENSE.txt
 *
 */
namespace Apptha\Airhotels\Controller\Index;


class Index extends \Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index
{
    public public function execute($coreRoute = null){

         $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance ();
         //$airhotelsKey = $objectManager->get ( 'Apptha\Airhotels\Helper\Product' )->AirhotelsKey();
         $moduleEnableornot = $objectManager->get ( 'Apptha\Airhotels\Helper\Data' )->getEnableFrontend();

         if ($moduleEnableornot == 0) {
               /**
               * Notification Message
               */
           $msg = base64_decode('PGgzIHN0eWxlPSJmbG9hdDpsZWZ0O2NvbG9yOnJlZDttYXJnaW46IDMwMHB4IDQ3NXB4OyB3aWR0aDoyNiU7IiBpZD0idGl0bGUtdGV4dCI+RW5hYmxlIEFpcmhvdGVscyB0byB2aWV3IHRoZSB3ZWJzaXRlPC9oMz4=');

           $this->getResponse()->setBody ( $msg );
        } else {
              return  parent::execute();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: replae  this line `public public function execute($coreRoute = null)`  to `public function execute($coreRoute = null){`

Comment: Thank you Rakesh, The site is now available

Comment: you most welcome. accept the answer if its works.